# TAutoObject in delphi lifecycle..?

Tags: delphi, object, automation, ole

I have a simple automation class like this:

```
type
  TTest_COM = class(TAutoObject, ITest_COM)
  private
    Variable: TClass;
  protected
    procedure Test(parameters...); safecall;
  public
    procedure  Initialize; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

destructor TTest_COM.Destroy;
begin
  Variable.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTest_COM.Initialize;
begin
  inherited;
  Variable := TClass.Create;
end;

procedure TTest_COM.Test(parameters...); safecall;
begin
  // this method makes use of "Variable"
end;
```

Could anyone explain to me the lifecycle of such com object which acts as a msmq receiver?

The problem is that the procedure: Test sometimes operates on not allocated "Variable".
When I remove the line: Variable.Free; It works perfectly okay in spite of the fact that the memory usage for the dllhost.exe grow up.

Why do such things happen?

EDIT:

Because I cannot answer on my own question. I am doing this here.

The problem solved.

The class was allocating the global variable. I haven't noticed that.

That was the problem that another variable was overwritten.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you create `Variable` in a constructor? Also, what is `TClass`?

Comment: I guess you are running this in COM+ so you could subclass `TMtsAutoObject` instead of `TAutoObject` and use OnActivate and OnDeactivate to create/free your variable. That is what I do for regular COM+ object. I have not tried it with a MSMQ listener.

Comment: @Marjan Venema because as a guest user (I assume) I got the information that after 6 or more hours I am able to do this :) It is ridiculous, but cannot do anything with that :)

Comment: @John: ah! Thanks for letting me know. Well, another reason to create an account I guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

The AutoObject should be freed when the reference count hits zero.

I suspect that the error is not in your code, but in the code that uses the object. In the code that uses your object the reference count hits zero and is destroyed, but the `Test` procedure is still called from that code on the freed object. That is why `Test` sometimes operates on a not allocated Variable: the `TTest_COM` object is already destroyed.